Does output count for space complexity in an algorithm?
It's controversial when I search answers on the internet. Most people tend to omit the space of output. However, when I search the space complexity of Floyd-Warshall algorithm, all shown are O(n^2) which stands for the returned matrix.

Yes, if you use "extra" space anywhere throughout your algorithm, it's part of space complexity.

"Most people tend to omit the space of output.": really? How have you measured that?

Others have asked this question, and most answers tend to omit.

Focus on communicating clearly instead of expecting that everyone uses exactly the same definition.

Yep. I plan to state clearly in my algorithm books.
